# Azure Block Blob: "The specified block list is invalid" when trying to create blocks and committing them

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-rest-api

I am trying to create the blocks and commit them in the same code using the below logic:

**PutStream.js**

```js
const request = require('request')
const fs = require('fs')
const account = 'Enter your container name here'
const containerName = 'stream-test-container'
const blobName = 'myBlob.txt'
const strTime = new Date().toUTCString()
const _ = require('lodash')
let i = 0
const blockIdArray = []
const token = 'Enter Your Token Here'
const readStream = fs.createReadStream('smallTextFile.txt', { highWaterMark: 50 })

readStream.on('data', function (chunk) {
  i++
  const blobContent = chunk
  const contentLength = chunk.length
  const blockId = Buffer.from('block' + i).toString('base64')
  blockIdArray.push(blockId)
  const optionsPutBlock = {
    url: `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/${containerName}/${blobName}?comp=block&blockid=${blockId}`,
    headers: {
      Authorization:
      `Bearer ${token}`,
      'x-ms-date': strTime,
      'x-ms-version': '2019-02-02',
      'Content-Length': contentLength
    },
    body: blobContent
  }
  request.put(optionsPutBlock, callbackPutBlock)
})

readStream.on('end', () => {
  const xmlBlockList = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><BlockList>' + (_.map(blockIdArray, (id) => { return `<Latest>${id}</Latest>` })).join('') + '</BlockList>'
  console.log(xmlBlockList)
  const xmlBlockListLength = new TextEncoder().encode(xmlBlockList).length
  const optionsPutBlockList = {
    url: `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/${containerName}/${blobName}?comp=blocklist`,
    headers: {
      Authorization:
      `Bearer ${token}`,
      'x-ms-date': strTime,
      'x-ms-version': '2019-02-02',
      'Content-Length': xmlBlockListLength,
      'Content-Type': 'application/text-plain'
    },
    body: xmlBlockList
  }
  console.log(optionsPutBlockList.body)
  request.put(optionsPutBlockList, callbackPutBlockList)
})

function callbackPutBlock (error, response, body) {
  console.log(response.statusCode, response.statusMessage, Block created)
  if (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}

function callbackPutBlockList (error, response, body) {
  console.log(response.statusCode, response.statusMessage)
  if (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

The contents of **`smallTextFile.txt`** are:

```
This is a small file. Hello from Nodejs. How are you? 
This is line number 2. Dumm text Lorem
This is line number 3 of the dummy text
This is line number 4 four.
```

Output of **`PutStream.js`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><BlockList><Latest>YmxvY2sx</Latest><Latest>YmxvY2sy</Latest><Latest>YmxvY2sz</Latest><Latest>YmxvY2s0</Latest></BlockList>
201 Created Block created
400 The specified block list is invalid.
201 Created Block created
201 Created Block created
201 Created Block created
```

When I try to run this it doesn't commit the blocks. I came to know this after I ran [`Get Block List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-block-list) after the above code `PutStream.js`, As all the blocks were in the uncommitted list.

Can anyone tell why does above logic doesn't readily commit blocks after creating them?

**References:**

1. [Put Block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block)
2. [Get Block List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-block-list)
3. [Put Block List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block-list)

Comment: I am able to run your code successfully. I believe you're running into this issue is because you have tried to upload a block blob with name `myBlob.txt` previously using put block which were never committed. Please try by giving a different name to your blob. That should work.

Comment: You might be able to run the code successfully the second time for a specific blob name. Try changing the blob name to a completely new blob name, it won't work the first time, but the second time when you run the same code it will work.

Comment: Changed the blob name to `myBlob1.txt` from `myBlob.txt` and it worked the first time as well.

Comment: I got the answer to my question I increased the size of my file to 1Mb and high watermark to 1024*256. I observed that somehow my code is sending PutBlockList requests even before the Blocks are created by PutBlock due to which it is failing. I somehow have to ensure that PutBlockList is called only after all the blocks have been uploaded.

Comment: Awesome! Please keep one thing in mind - length of your block ids must be the same. With your current code you will run into the same issue when the number of blocks become 10 or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue** committing the blocks : Above code is sending PutBlockList requests even before the Blocks are created by PutBlock due to which it is failing.

**Solution** : The problem  committing blocks got resolved  by increasing the size of file to 1Mb and high watermark to 1024*256  and by making sure that PutBlockList is called only after all the blocks have been uploaded . Thanks to [@mayank patel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15326879/mayank-patel).

> Note: keep length of the  block ids same as  issue may arise  when the
> number of blocks become 10 or more ,as suggested by [@gaurav
> mantri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188096/gaurav-mantri)